# Api rails: no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl

I did a rails 5 api with [Sourcey](http://sourcey.com/building-the-prefect-rails-5-api-only-app/) tutorial and now i get a routing error.

Curl command **`curl -H "Authorization: Token token=8NjQH4YVWQdUIve4xDQBaArr" http://localhost:3000/v1/users`** display a 404 not found message and 'no route matches' is raised in my term where the server is running

> No route matches [GET] "/v1/users"

So i checked **`rails routes`**. The output is:

```
v1_users GET    /v1/users(.:format)     api/v1/users#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
         POST   /v1/users(.:format)     api/v1/users#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
 v1_user GET    /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
         PATCH  /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
         PUT    /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
         DELETE /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

we notice we have GET /v1/users and /:id

How to solve this problem ?

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api' do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :users
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Users_controller.rb and api_controller.rb are inside **/app/controller/api/v1/**.

If you need another part of the code (controllers, models ....) do not hesitate to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your route has a subdomain constraint. So that your api would only be available at `http://api.example.com/v1/users`.

You cannot use subdomains with localhost without setting up a virtual host via apache or nginx, editing the hosts file or using a service like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

You could also convert it to a path constraint instead:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I juste let 'scope module: 'api' do' and i didn't add 'namespace 'api' do' to use curl with url http://api.example.com/v1/users

Comment: Yeah thats only if you wanted `http://example.com/api/v1/users` instead. If you setup a tunnel so that you can access your rails server with a subdomain you don't need to alter your routes.